Differentiation of a product of functions
If I have three (vector)functions, all dependent on different (complex)variables:
\begin{equation}
a = X^{\mu_1}(z_1, \bar{z}_1), 
b = X^{\mu_2}(z_2, \bar{z}_2), 
c= X^{\mu_3}(z_3, \bar{z}_3)
\end{equation}
I am interested in the consecutive derivative with respect to $z_1$, and $\bar{z}_1$ (I write $\partial_1$ meaning $\partial_{z_1}$, likewise for the conjugate). And I also have some relation for $\partial_{1}\bar{\partial}_{1}(ab)$, $\partial_{1}\bar{\partial}_{1}(ac)$ which I want to single out.
Attempt at solution:
Using the product rule and that functions $b$ and $c$ are independent of $z_1, \bar{z}_1$ I get:
\begin{equation}
\partial_1\bar{\partial}_1(abc) = \partial_1(\bar{\partial}_1(ab)c+ab\bar{\partial}_1c)=\partial_1\bar{\partial}_1(ab)c
\end{equation}
But also:
\begin{equation}
\partial_1\bar{\partial}_1(abc) = \partial_1(\bar{\partial}_1(ac)b+ac\bar{\partial}_1b)=\partial_1\bar{\partial}_1(ac)b
\end{equation}
Which would give:
\begin{equation}
\partial_1\bar{\partial}_1(abc) = \frac{1}{2}\partial_1\bar{\partial}_1(ab)c + \frac{1}{2}\partial_1\bar{\partial}_1(ac)b
\end{equation}
Right? My problem is the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$, which in my reference does not show up. Any reason why it should not be there?

I am not sure how you are using the vector functions. Are you contracting things such that $(ab)$ is a scalar and $(ac)$ is a scalar? Otherwise I expect the order of the vectors to matter. Note also that taking derivatives with respect to a complex conjugate means that you don't have analytic functions, but rather consider the real and imaginary parts of $z=x+i y$ to be independent variables; then factors of two 2 abound such as $\partial_z=(\partial_x-i\partial_y)/2$

What you do is correct, although you coud just as well divide the weight factors over the terms differently, e.g. like:
\begin{equation}
\partial_1\bar{\partial}_1(abc) = {\small\frac{1}{5}}\partial_1\bar{\partial}_1(ab)c + {\small\frac45}\partial_1\bar{\partial}_1(ac)b
\end{equation}
Anyhow it is crucial that $b$ and $c$ really are both independent of $z_1$ and $\bar{z}_1$, so there might be some subtle reason why that does not hold (which we cant see without having your reference, so it is an error, but we just can't be sure yet who made the error.)
